# if i have two text objects how to tell the difference in browser javascript

Tags: javascript

so say i have a html file with this data in it

```
<html>
    <a class="text">hello</a>
    <a class="text">how are you</a>
</html>
```

how would i get the text with "how are you" with a querySelector

i have tried to do `document.querySelector("how are you");` but it wont work

another thing i have tried was `document.querySelector('[class="text"]:contains("how are you")');` but it gave me an error

Comment: yes it helped me thank you